# Idempotent generators of the four binary QR codes of length 7

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, coding-theory, idempotents

I have a coding theory assignment and I thought it would be a good idea to double check before I hand it in. I'm asked to find the idempotent generators of the four binary QR codes C1, C2, C3, C4, of length 7. Here's what I came up with:

The cyclotomic cosets would be: {0}, {1, 2, 4}, {3, 6, 5},
and the idempotents in $R_7$ are 
$$
\begin{aligned}
&0, 1 = x^0,\\ 
&x+x^2+x^4, \\
&x^3+x^6+x^5,\\
&1+x+x^2+x^4,\\
&1+x^3+x^6+x^5,\\ 
&x+x^2+x^4+x^3+x^6+x^5, \\
\text{and}\qquad &\\
& 1 +x+x^2+x^4+x^3+x^6+x^5.
\end{aligned}
$$